# How to create a minimal PDF file according to PDF-2.0 spec without a corrupted document structure

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to recreate the "Minimal PDF file" example from the PDF-2.0 standard, as found here:
https://www.iso.org/standard/63534.html

A free and similar "Minimal PDF file" example can be found in the previous PDF-1.7 standard (page 707):
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

The problem I am having is that whatever I try, I always end up with a pdf that has a corrupted document structure according to Acrobat Reader / Acrobat Pro. In practice this means that it does open my pdf succesfully and shows the pages correctly, but whenever I try to close the file Acrobat Reader / Pro tries to fix the pdf and prompts a save. I don't want this, I want my PDF's to comply with the standard from the start.

Here is my code for the PDF-2.0 "Minimal PDF file":

```
%PDF-2.0
%����

1 0 obj
  <</Type /Catalog
    /Pages 2 0 R
    /Metadata 5 0 R
  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  <</Type /Pages
    /Kids [3 0 R]
  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  <</Type /Page
    /Parent 2 0 R
    /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
    /Contents 4 0 R
    /Resources <<>>
  >>
endobj

4 0 obj
  <</Length 1
  >>
stream

endstream
endobj

5 0 obj
  <</Type /Metadata
    /SubType /XML
    /Length 1381
  >>
stream
<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3">
      <pdf:Producer>name of software which generates the PDF</pdf:Producer>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
      <xmp:CreatorTool>name of tool used to create the document</xmp:CreatorTool>
      <xmp:CreateDate>2019-09-04T20:57:49+02:00</xmp:CreateDate>
      <xmp:ModifyDate>2019-09-04T20:57:49+02:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
      <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
      <dc:title>
        <rdf:Alt>
          <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">document title</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
      </dc:title>
      <dc:creator>
        <rdf:Seq>
          <rdf:li>document author's personal name</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Seq>
      <dc:creator>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
      <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:6cb4b2d9-6bb9-45b3-98b7-b5017ec34351</xmpMM:DocumentID>
      <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:859fb9d9-08bd-4cb1-9ca2-035973ec93ec</xmpMM:InstanceID>
    </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>

<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65535 f
0000000024 00000 n
0000000101 00000 n
0000000157 00000 n
0000000280 00000 n
0000000333 00000 n

trailer
  <</Size 6
    /Root 1 0 R
  >>
startxref
1972
%%EOF
```

I am mostly interested in a solution for the PDF-2.0 standard, but I am aware that this standard isn't freely available so I am also happy with a solution for the PDF-1.7 standard. My PDF-1.7 "Minimal PDF file" code:

```
%PDF-1.4
%¥±ë

1 0 obj
  << /Type /Catalog
     /Outlines 2 0 R
     /Pages 3 0 R
  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  << /type Outlines
     /Count 0
  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  << /Type /Pages
     /Kids [4 0 R]
     /Count 1
  >>
endobj

4 0 obj
  >> /Type /Page
     /Parent 3 0 R
     /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
     /Contents 5 0 R
     /Resources << /ProcSet 6 0 R >>
  >>
endobj

5 0 obj
  << /Length 29 >>
stream
...Page-marking operators...
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
  [/PDF]
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000018 00000 n
0000000098 00000 n
0000000153 00000 n
0000000225 00000 n
0000000369 00000 n
0000000450 00000 n

trailer
  << /Size 7
     /Root 1 0 R
  >>
startxref
475
%%EOF
```

I have tried the following things to solve this problem:

- Inspected the 'fixed' pdf's Acrobat Reader / Pro returned after saving and tried finding the differences. This is almost impossible, because the 'fixed' file is completely changed to something else;
- I tried using the Preflight tool in Acrobat Pro. It does have a profile called: "Report PDF syntax issues", but that only returns: "The document structure is corrupt" and nothing else;
- Working with PDF files that do work and slowly deleting small parts. This did work, but after a while I end up in the same situation, suddenly the document structure becomes corrupt when I haven't changed anything relevant (as far as I know).

Additional info:

- For the End of Line Sequence I use "LF";
- The byte offset is calculated using a small bit of JavaScript code that basically consists of this: new Blob([`pdf content`]).size;
- You can copy and paste the above code in a text editor and save it as a .pdf and you should be able to recreate my problem.

Comment: Is each of your cross reference entries exactly 20 bytes in size?

Comment: You are brilliant @mkl That was exactly it. I changed it on both files and now they both work! Can you submit this as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

You could use this from the official standard: "Following this line are the cross-reference entries themselves, one per line. Each entry shall be exactly 20 bytes long, including the end-of-line marker." (page 40)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common error when constructing a pdf manually is ignoring details of the pdf cross reference specification, in particular the entry size required therein:

> Each entry shall be exactly 20 bytes long, including the end-of-line marker.

*(ISO 32000-1 section 7.5.4 'Cross-Reference Table')*

As it turned out, this was the issue here, too.